# Nignx Reverse Proxy not loading css and js files.

Tags: nginx, centos, asp.net

Hi I am running dotnet core on CentOS 7 with nginx reverse proxy. Following are my configurations.

```
   server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name  freebitcoins.zone www.freebitcoins.zone;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        ssl_certificate "/home/Ssl/freebitcoins.zone.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/home/Ssl/freebitcoins.zone.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;


        location / {
        autoindex on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /websocket/ {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name freebitcoins.zone www.freebitcoins.zone;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

The problem I am facing is , its not loading css or js files (all static).
[image]

I do get the following errors in Asp.net Core Logging.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 0.7387ms 404
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://freebitcoins.zone/web_assets/images/logo.png
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 0.3727ms 404
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://freebitcoins.zone/favicon.ico
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 0.5379ms 404
```

Please help me what I have done wrong or whats the issue. Its eating my head for 3 days now.

Comment: To make it even worse, sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Anyone who is stuck here. The thing is simple.

```
dotnet /home/freeExWeb/freeExWeb.dll &
```

This will not load css or js files for some reason.

But if you run the dotnet process from its own directory. Woala!

```
cd /home/freeExWeb/
dotnet freeExWeb.dll &
```